# Configuring Grunt multiple targets

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to configure two `uglify` targets:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      development: {
        options: {
          banner: '// DEVELOPMENT\n',
          report: 'gzip'
        },
        build: {
          src: 'js/**/*.js',
          dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
        }
      },

      production: {
        options: {
          banner: '// PRODUCTION\n'
        },
        build: {
          src: 'js/**/*.js',
          dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify:production']);
};
```

Neither `uglify:development` nor `uglify:production` produces any output nor errors.

The task runs fine if I don't use any targets (just adding `options` and `build` directory to `uglify` object).

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is that you must've copied it from somewhere, and assumed that `build` was part of a target, when in reality the options applied to every target, and `build` was *a* target.

`options` can be either target-specific or apply to every target.

Try it like this:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      development: {
        options: {
          banner: '// DEVELOPMENT\n',
          report: 'gzip'
        },
        src: 'js/**/*.js',
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      },

      production: {
        options: {
          banner: '// PRODUCTION\n'
        },
        src: 'js/**/*.js',
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      }
    }
  });
```